# Splash screen with horizontal progressBar with using coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, android-progressbar

I am trying to create splash screen with progressBar. I want create it with using coroutines. Here is my code:

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen)
        progressBarLoading = findViewById(R.id.loadingProgress)
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            delay(1000)
            if (progressBarStatus < 100) {
                progressBarLoading?.setProgress(progressBarStatus)
                progressBarStatus = progressBarStatus + 30

            } else {
                var intent = Intent(this@SplashActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
        }
    }
```

but when splash screen is showing , progress Bar doesn't move and absent switching to the second screen. I can't understand what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just calling your code once . you need to do something like

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
            while(true){
                delay(1000)

                if (progressBarStatus < 100) {
                    progressBarLoading?.setProgress(progressBarStatus)
                    progressBarStatus += 30

                } else {
                    var intent = Intent(this@SplashActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                    finish()
                    break
                }
            }
        }
```